# Did Early Church Fathers have a Talmud of their own?

Tags: bible, early-church, church-fathers

The Talmud(s) are compiled of about 2,711 pages. The Mishna, Midrash, and Gemara are many examples of Jewish literature that encompasses every-day life, from halacha (Jewish law) to marriage and worship. All in all, Rabbinic Judaism is an immense-sized religion. Other than the writings of the early Church fathers and the Bible, do Christians have similar sized-volumes of law codes and debates, or interpretations of laws codes and commentaries in Christianity?

Comment: The basic answer is No, but I'm not sure what else you might want in an answer.

Comment: @MattGutting Would other contemporaneous or earlier church father writings count as an equivalence though?  By St. Thomas time, I would say [Lombard's Sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentences) seem to be treated similarly.  Of course the genre of those are not stories like in the Talmud.  Then there is the Canon law.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple The Canon Law looks interesting. It is similar to halacha (Jewish law)?

Comment: @TurkHill This [reddit comments](https://www.reddit.com/r/Christianity/comments/614gr5/how_is_canon_law_different_from_halachasharia_is/) should serve as a quick comparison.  An excellent treatment of canon law is from the [Catholic encyclopedia entry](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/09056a.htm)

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Thank you.

Comment: Your title question - "did Early Church Fathers have a Talmud" - is much different from the question in the body - "Do Christians have similar sized-volumes of law codes and debates."  Could you clarify which of these two questions you are looking to answer?  They are not the same question.  Thanks

Comment: @guest37 Thank you for your comment but I think they are the same question since Talmud mostly comprises of "volumes of law codes and debates."

Comment: Yes, but in the title you are asking about "Early Church Fathers", but in the body about "Christians".   The first group is relatively narrow, but since the early Church Fathers Christianity has fragmented into hundreds of different groups with different beliefs.  What might be held by one group, say Roman Catholics, might be completely different than, say, Calvinists.  You didn't tag your post to relate to any particular group - only "bible"

Comment: @guest37 I added church-fathers and early church into my question as tags. I am specifically asking about the early church.

Comment: The 'Talmud' of the early Church would be, essentially, a collection of the Fathers.

Comment: The writings of the Church Fathers are for historical Christianity what Talmudic or rabbinic writings are for traditional Judaism. For systematic collections of these writings, see [Patrologia Graeca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrologia_Graeca), [Patrologia Latina](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrologia_Latina), and [Patrologia Orientalis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrologia_Orientalis).

Comment: @Lucian Thank you. I agree with you.